# Spectral decomposition of idele class group $L^2(\mathbb{I}_F/ F^{\times})$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, sp.spectral-theory, adeles

Let $F$ be a number field. Let $\mathbb{A}_F$ be the ring of adeles. The group of units of $\mathbb{A}_F$ is called the group of ideles $\mathbb{I}_F=\mathbb{A}_F^{\times}= GL_1(\mathbb{A}_F)$. The quotient $\mathbb{I}_F/ F^{\times} = GL_1(\mathbb{A}_F)/ GL_1(F)$ is called the idele class group of $F$. My question is how to decompose the $L^2$ space $L^2(\mathbb{I}_F/ F^{\times})$? Here we let $L^2(\mathbb{I}_F/ F^{\times})$ be the completion of $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{I}_F/ F^{\times})$ with respect to the usual $L^2$-norm given by $\vert \vert f \rvert \rvert^2= \int_{\mathbb{I}_F/ F^{\times}} \vert f(g) \rvert^2 dg$ for $f \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{I}_F/ F^{\times})$ and usual inner product $(f,F)$.

I know the following theorem: For a compact abelian group $G$ with total measure 1, the continuous group homomorphisms (characters) $\psi:G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ form an orthonormal Hilbert-space basis for $L^2(G)$. That is, $L^2(G)=$ completion of $\bigoplus_{\psi} \mathbb{C} \psi$. And we also have $f= \sum_{\psi} (f,\psi) \psi$ for $f \in L^2(G)$.

The above theorem works for many useful cases. For example, $G= \mathbb{A}_F/ F$ which is compact, we pick $\psi$ as additive characters on $G$. Hence the above theorem is the Fourier theory for $\mathbb{A}_F/ F$. However, for our case, the group $\mathbb{I}_F/ F^{\times}$ is not compact. So we cannot apply the theorem directly. My naive idea is that we may think the 1-idele subgroup $\mathbb{I}_F^1:= \{ x \in \mathbb{I}_F; \vert x \rvert=1 \}$. Note that $F^{\times}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{I}_F^1$ and the quotient $\mathbb{I}_F^1/ F^{\times}$ is compact now. We may apply the above theorem and pick $\psi$ as Hecke characters. This gives the spectral decomposition for $L^2(\mathbb{I}_F^1/ F^{\times})$. We also have the isomorphism $\mathbb{I}_F/ F^{\times} \cong  \mathbb{I}_F^1/ F^{\times} \times \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. So I think we should also have a similar spectral decomposition for $L^2(\mathbb{I}_F/ F^{\times})$ (Consider $L^2(\mathbb{C}^{\times})$ and $L^2(\mathbb{S}^1)$, note that $\mathbb{C}^{\times} \cong \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $\mathbb{S}^1$ is compact). However, I cannot find any references on it. Thanks a lot for help!